# Configuring a Maven plugin twice in a pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I am working on a large `Maven` Java project that contains suites of `TestNG` automated tests and also suites of `Cucumber` automated tests. I realise that this is not ideal, but the different test suites were written by different sub-teams at different stages of the project. Going forward we intend to split this project out into smaller projects, but for now we are stuck with this mix.

The `surefire` plugin can be used to run these tests from `Maven`, but the plugin needs to be configured differently for each in our `pom.xml`.

For `Cucumber`, we are using it in conjunction with `cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin` and it is configured like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>${threads}</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/Parallel*IT.class</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

For our `TestNG` tests, it is configured like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>${file}</suiteXmlFiles>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>suitethreadpoolsize</name>
                        <value>${threads}</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

We are not `Maven` experts and so, at the moment, we simply comment out the version of the plugin that we do not want to use for the suite we are running. Obviously this is cumbersome and not best practice, so I would be very grateful for any advice as to how we should address this. Can we legitimately define the plugin twice in the pom.xml and somehow pass a flag to indicate which version should be run? Many thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Integrations tests should be done using maven-failsafe-plugin...which has a default naming schema...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to select the proper configuration:

add this snippet:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>Cucumber</id>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>${threads}</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/Parallel*IT.class</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>TestNG</id>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>${file}</suiteXmlFiles>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>suitethreadpoolsize</name>
                            <value>${threads}</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and change this

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.1</version>
    </plugin>
   <!-- delete on of the entries -->
</plugins>
```

you have to pecify the desired profile at the command line:

```
   mvn test -P Cucumber
   mvn test -P TestNG
```

bit you can also run both at once:

```
mvn test -P Cucumber -P TestNG 
mvn test -P Cucumber,TestNG
```

Comment: Also you can add many profile for your tests(cuke and TestNG) as well e.g. smoke, full etc.

Comment: I made the changes suggested above and my tests are now working as desired. I very much appreciate the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a downstream maven project for each set of tests you want to run. More work up front but it pays off pretty quickly.

Comment: Yes, good answer - thank you. This will be the long term plan. In the short term, I implemented the suggestions in the other answer and they worked great.

Comment: Great you found a solution that works for you. I found that profiles makes it harder to make reproducible builds. That may or may not be relevant to you.